# How to detect when a view is being removed

Tags: android

I have built a simple system that allows the user to update views throughout the application whenever a linked image file on disk has changed (the App has a bunch of drawing operations that let you change the images).

It works by maintaining a list of `FileUpdateListeners` which contain a `File` and a `View`. Whenever a `SaveTask` is created for a `File`, it will run through all the listeners and call any listeners hooked to that `File`.

Now it appears the Views are constantly dropped and remade as you move forward and backward through Activities. However, the listeners all stick around. I´m guessing because their reference to the View prevents it from being garbage collected. I´m pretty sure this is going to wreck the performance and eventually cause the app to run out of memory.

So my question: Is it possible to detect when a View is unhooked from the Activity, so that I can remove the Listener that it belongs to? Or is there another way to make sure the Listeners are removed when the Views are removed?

Ideally, the Listener should not be inside the `View`. I'd want the system to work with any kind of View.

Comment: get a look to : `OnLayoutChangeListener`

Comment: Also check [java.lang.ref.WeakReference<T>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and [java.util.WeakHashMap<K, V>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html). These classes allow you to keep references to objects without preventing them from being garbage collected.

Comment: `View.onAttachedToWindow` and `View.onDetachedFromWindow`